# PostgreSQL Junction Table to a key-value store (like Kyoto Cabinet)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, nosql, kyotocabinet

I am not sure what type of question this is.

What import format(s) does Kyoto Cabinet support?

For example, I have a junction table `t`, many-to-many relationship, in a PostgreSQL database.  The size of `t` is about 285 million.

```
t =
X, Y
-----
1, a
1, b
2, a
2, c
3, c
3, d
4, b
4, e
```

What is the easiest, fastest way to export, then import to some key-value store like Kyoto Cabinet?

So that I end up with:

```
db = 
db[1] = [a,b]
db[2] = [a,c]
db[3] = [c,d]
db[4] = [b,e]
```

My preferred language is Ruby.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. you want a query that outputs this as text? Or some other datatype? Verbatim? Or just the values?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I have updated my question: What import format(s) does Kyoto Cabinet support?

Comment: I can help with Postgres, but have no experience with Kyoto Cabinet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the values:

```
SELECT x, array_agg(y ORDER BY y)
FROM   t
GROUP  BY x;
```

Yields an `array`. If you want `text` use `string_agg(y, ',' ORDER BY y)`.
Probably faster:

```
SELECT x, array_agg(y)
FROM  (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY x,y) t
GROUP  BY x;
```

Comment: This sql query helped me out immensely.  Kyoto Cabinet has a [setBulk](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/rubydoc/KyotoCabinet/DB.html#method-i-set_bulk) method for bulk inserts.  Your query helped me get the data ready for calling this.